# How to echo "!echo"?

Tags: batch-file, echo

How do I echo *!echo* in a batch file?

```
echo !echo !Percent! Percent>>test.txt
```

Doesn't output the !echo to the file. It only outputs

```
40 Percent
```

When I open the txt it should be:

```
!echo 40 Percent
```

How do I fix this please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `!` try:

```
echo ^^!echo !Percent! Percent>>test.txt
```

And that should solve your problem.

Mona

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks a ton!